# Change CSS background color in jQuery on timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, countdowntimer

I have to create a function in JQuery on the timer from the plugin wordpress Quiz and survey Master.

As long as the timer hasn't passed 45 minutes it's displayed in green but when it exceeds it must be displayed in red (for information the timer is a countdown timer and predifined on 3 hours at the moment).

in my research i know I have to use the `css` function like this

```
$('div.mlw_qmn_timer').css("background-color": "green");
$('div.mlw_qmn_timer').css("background-color": "red");
```

so I haven't any idea how I can get the 45 minutes to change the background on the beginning of the 3 hours.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setTimeout` to change the color after 45 minutes.

```
// Initially, set the background as green
$('div.mlw_qmn_timer').css("background-color", "green");

var interval = 45 * 60 * 1000; // `setTimeout` accepts time in millis

// Change the color to red after 45 minutes    
setTimeout(function() {
  $('div.mlw_qmn_timer').css("background-color", "red");
}, interval);
```

Following is a demo which does the exact thing, but with an interval of 10 seconds:

```js
// Initially, set the background as green
$('div.mlw_qmn_timer').css("background-color", "green");

var interval = 10000; // `setTimeout` accepts time in millis

// Change the color to red after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  $('div.mlw_qmn_timer').css("background-color", "red");
}, interval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mlw_qmn_timer">test</div>
```

Comment: i had another information, i use the plugin wordpress quizz and survey (quizz master next) and i custom it so are you sure set timeout does'nt have a negative impact on the timer, for example it stops the timer when it should continue but with the red color? thanks for your response

Comment: @adrienjolion -- Please create another question for this.

Comment: your proposition is functional but there is a little bug , the timer flashes for one second in green then goes back to red with the timeout function, how i can fix it ?

Comment: @adrienjolion -- It is not possible with the code I have written. `setTimeout` executes the code only after the interval given has been expired. See the snippet which I just attached to my answer.